# Users are "logging in as others" on Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, session, cookies, cache-control

We're having a unique issue that is affecting a small handful of users from around the world. Nothing connects them aside from the fact they are all using Chrome for iOS.

Intermittently, users will login to our application (https://www.mousehuntgame.com) and appear to be "someone else". This issue cropped up recently during a period when no new code had been pushed to the site.

Of course the first thing we checked was that our authentication was not bugged or that the user's hash (stored in either cookies or a PHP session) was not crossing connections somewhere. The issue is not in the authentication system, and it only affects users using Chrome for iOS. The same users using Safari no longer see the issue.

We have the following PHP headers being sent to prevent caching:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, private");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

The "target users" that these users "turn into" are not yet confirmed to be also using Chrome. The solution for them to simply stop using the browser is not an option as others who continue to use Chrome can still gain access to these accounts.

Can Chrome be somehow caching cookies and "sharing" them across users? Could this be a DNS issue where it sees a mobile user agent and in order to save loading time it retrieves cached information and hands it off without further checking who the user is? This is a stretch, I know, but it's been a strange issue and we're grasping at straws now.

Comment: Just found this site: [Data Compression Proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression)   

We will try to add "Cache-Control: no-transform" to our headers and see if that helps. Could the SPDY protocol be somehow related to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Chrome Data Compression proxy.

I'd be very surprised if the Chrome proxy were at fault here, since we respect standard caching headers. That said, there could be a bug. If you can try to reproduce with and without the proxy that would be helpful. Another way to test is to open the page in an Incognito tab (which does not use the proxy).

(Edited)

I looked at some of the headers we are seeing from your site, and they include things like

Cache-Control: max-age=2592000

which means these responses are publicly cacheable for 30 days. I see a wide range of caching headers from many different URLs on the site, suggesting that your caching rules aren't being applied as widely as you thought; but of course I don't know the structure of the site and whether that would lead to the problem you are describing.

Feel free to reach out (email is fine too) and I'm happy to help debug if you still think this is a problem on our end.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The bug is not easily reproduced, however, after adding "no-transform" to avoid the proxy, we have received another user report about this issue.  
Your discovery that our site is not applying our caching rules across the board is helpful! There may be some gremlins hiding there.  
Can you give an example of a URL where you found the "max-age=2592000" rule? Thanks again.

Comment: We found that our forum page was not applying the same cache-control rules due it being plugged in vBulletin software. We've applied the headers to this page and will closely monitor for this issue.

Comment: Seems the issue has been resolved. Thanks for spotting the faulty cache-control headers on some URLs! The initial change to use "no-transform" on the main landing page after logging in fixed users who were "switching" immediately upon login. The second change to the headers on the forum page fixed users who were "switching" during normal navigation.

Comment: I take it back. A new report came in today. Someone logged into their account via Chrome on their iPhone and they appeared as someone else. If you have any other insights, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It could well be that our cache is serving old (cached) versions of the content since it had 30-day expiration. I am still seeing responses from your site with the 30-day expiration though, e.g.,:

/images/items/trinkets/2b33a9bc6f40c547e693173ce0851002.gif?cv=213

Comment: The image being cached longer should not affect users. The only items that should never cache are PHP files, which should now be the case. Are you seeing any faulty headers for PHP files?

Comment: Yes, many, but I don't know what implications this has for your game's behavior.

Examples: 
/forum/image.php?u=19471&dateline=1335969400
/forum/css.php?styleid=8&langid=1&d=1394039872&td=ltr&sheet=additional.css
/turn.php